# How to Store data json into cookies in javascript

Tags: javascript, web, cookies

I need help from you. Can you guide me, please?
I use JSON as data accounts. But, I need to create a session with a cookie.
The case is when I successfully logged in, the cookie was created, but only a user that I logged in was created. Not all of the objects in data JSON.

The JSON file is:

```json
{ "users": [{
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
        "username": "john20",
        "password": "doe20"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Julia",
        "last_name": "Chan",
        "email": "juliachan@gmail.com",
        "username": "julia19",
        "password": "chan19"
    }
    ]
}
```

So when I logged in with the username **julia19** with a true password, I will be logged in and the cookie was created with full information about username **julia19** (id, first_name, last_name, email, username, password) .

I using

```js
document.cookie = JSON.stringify(jcontent);
```

but it shows all of the objects in the JSON file.

The full file is:

```js
var ajaxhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "./data/accounts.json";

ajaxhttp.open("GET", url, true);
ajaxhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type","application/json");
ajaxhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(ajaxhttp.readyState == 4 && ajaxhttp.status == 200) {
        var jcontent = JSON.parse(ajaxhttp.responseText);
        document.addEventListener("submit", validateForm);
        function validateForm(e) {
            let uName = document.getElementById("username").value;
            let pWord = document.getElementById("password").value;

            if(jcontent.users.find(r => r.username == uName && r.password == pWord)) {
                document.cookie = JSON.stringify(jcontent);
                alert("Successfully login!")
            }
            else {
                e.preventDefault()
                alert("Username or Password is wrong!");
            }
        }
    }
}

ajaxhttp.send(null);


//Focus Field
document.querySelector("#username").focus();

// //Keypress
document.getElementById("username").addEventListener("keypress", keyUsr);
document.getElementById("password").addEventListener("keypress", keyPass);

function keyUsr(u) {
    if(u.keyCode === 32) {
        alert ("Space keys are not allowed");
        document.getElementById("username").value="";
    }
}

function keyPass(p) {
    if(p.keyCode === 32) {
        alert ("Space keys are not allowed");
        document.getElementById("password").value="";
    }
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,200,300);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

center {
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 340px; padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
  color: #666;
  text-decoration: none;
}

  a:hover {
  color: #4FDA8C; }

input { font: 16px/26px "Raleway", sans-serif; }

body {
  background-color: #f1f2f2;
  font: 16px/26px "Raleway", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  background: white;
  color: black;}

.form-wrap {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 320px;
  margin: 3em auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px #BEBEBE;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px #BEBEBE;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px #BEBEBE;
}

.form-wrap .tabs { overflow: hidden; }

.form-wrap .tabs h3 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.form-wrap .tabs h3 a {
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: #e6e7e8;
  display: block;
  color: #666;
}

.form-wrap .tabs h3 a.active { background-color: #fff; }

.form-wrap .tabs-content { padding: 1.5em; }

.form-wrap .tabs-content div[id$="tab-content"] { display: none; }

.form-wrap .tabs-content .active { display: block !important; }

.form-wrap form .input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  padding: .8em 0 10px .8em;
  border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 .8em 0;
  padding-right: 2em;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-wrap form .button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: .8em 0 10px .8em;
  background-color: #28A55F;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.form-wrap form .button:hover { background-color: #4FDA8C; }

.form-wrap form .checkbox {
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: .5em 0 1.5em;
}

.form-wrap form .checkbox:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}

.form-wrap form label[for] {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-wrap form label[for]:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    top: 0px;
    left: -14px;
}

.form-wrap form label[for]:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
    top: 4px;
    left: -10px;
    border: 3px solid #28A55F;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.form-wrap .help-text { margin-top: .6em; }

.form-wrap .help-text p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.text-logo {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Archivo", sans-serif!important;
  color: var(--black)!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">

        <!-- Google Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- Custom StyleSheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/form-login.css" />

        <title>Onbena Shop</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1 class="text-logo">ONBENA SHOP</h1>
            <h2><b>Login</b></h2>
            <p>You need to login before access it</p>
            <form method="post" id="login">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control">
                    <span id="help-error"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                    <span id="help-error"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" onclick = "addCookie()">
                    <a href="./" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
                </div>
                <p>Don't have an account? <a href="register.html">Sign up now</a>.</p>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script src="./js/login.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're storing the whole `jcontent` variable.
Maybe, you thought `jcontent.find()` will eliminate the other objects, but it doesn't.

There are different approaches for this but you can do this

```
// Store what you found in a variable
const user = jcontent.users.find(r => r.username == uName && r.password == pWord)

// Checks if the user variable is empty or not
if(user) {
    // Stringify if there is one.
    document.cookie = JSON.stringify(user);
    alert("Successfully login!")
} else {
    e.preventDefault()
    alert("Username or Password is wrong!");
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I see... when the user success to find the object, it can be converting with `JSON.stringify`. I think I must insert the variable 'jcontent' first to declare the object JSON. Thank you for helping, I understand now :)